# Python socket connect time out on OS X Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, osx-mavericks

I just purchased a Macbook Pro and I'm having trouble with some python code that works fine on Windows and Linux. The issue showed up in [Rackspace's Flanker](https://github.com/mailgun/flanker) project.

I've distilled the issue down into this short test script.

```
import socket

host = 'gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(1.0)
s.connect((host, 25))
s.close()
```

This works fine on Windows and Linux (completes with no output), but it's throwing an exception (a timeout) on my Mac. I've asked a friend to run this on his Mac and it results in the same timeout.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>

    s.connect((host, 25))

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth

    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)

socket.timeout: timed out
```

I'm thinking it might be an OS X network configuration issue. I'm using Python 2.7.5, which is stock on my installation, but I've tried 2.7.8 as well.

---

Additional info 1:

Netcat (nc -vv gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25), as recommended by admdrew, results in the following.

```
nc: connectx to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com port 25 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out
nc: connectx to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com port 25 (tcp) failed: No route to host
```

So it's certainly not specific to python.

---

Additional info 2:

I've realized that netcat on my linux VM, and a windows version of it, both fail. So I'm confident  FIOS is blocking port 25. So the question becomes, "Why is Python's socket connect succeeding on Windows, but failing on OS X, when port 25 is blocked for both according to netcat?"

Thanks, all, for the help.

Comment: What happens when you try to netcat to that host in OSX (`nc -vv gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25`)?

Comment: Same result, so I guess python isn't the issue. I will modify the post with the exact output.

Comment: many ISPs block traffic over port 25. is this your issue or does it work from another machine on the same network?

Comment: Other machines on the same network work fine.

Comment: I would have to assume then that you have some kind of firewall blocking you.

Comment: I'm starting to think it's [FIOS](http://www.verizon.com/Support/Residential/internet/highspeed/general+support/top+questions/questionsone/124274.htm)... I just don't understand why my pc works and the mac doesn't. The mac is wireless... maybe it's less trusted.